# Why are the "bash" and the "source" commands behaving differently?

Tags: environment-variables, scripts

I'm using Mac OS 10.8. I ran the `/sw/fink/bin/init.sh` script using the `bash` command which was supposed to make the `fink/bin` folder part of the `$PATH` variable for the current session.

The fink command didn't work, so I ran the script again with the `.` command which I was told was equivalent to the `source` command; I was able to call fink now without an absolute path.

Why did `.` work and not `bash`? Is it because the `sh` and `bash` commands run with their own temporary `$PATH` variable?

Comment: Mac OS 10.8 is a derivative of Ubuntu since when?

Comment: This is also relevant to Ubuntu users, don't be a d**k

Comment: No it is not otherwise you would have used Ubuntu in the topic. Different OS's have different ways of doing things and all we know is about how Ubuntu works. So -all- answers you get will be based on Ubuntu and it can be very very dangerous (well probably not in this case ;) ) to assume methods that work on Ubuntu work on other systems that are not Ubuntu related. And if even MINT questions get hammered down why would MAC OS stay open? If anything this should have been asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ and not here. And please do not blame me when you are doing it wrongly ;)

Answer (score 3):

`bash somescript` will start a new `bash` shell, evaluate your script and then exit. The script will see a copy of your current environment, but any changes will be discarded when the script ends.

`. somescript` or `source somescript` will evaluate the script in your current context, so changes to existing environment variables, or the setting of new ones, will be retained.